# How to get/read picture from Excel file (xlsx) using EPPlus

Tags: c#, epplus

Let's assume I have a worksheet named `sheet1` which contain a picture named `pic_001` How can I get this picture as `System.Drawing.Image` object.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

OK I found out how to:

```
public static Image GetImage(string sheetname, ExcelPackage excelFile)
    {
      var sheet = excelFile.Workbook.Worksheets[sheetname];
      var pic = sheet.Drawings["pic_001"] as ExcelPicture;
      return pic.Image;
    }
```

Comment: how do I use this If I have a sheet, where every row has a cell with an image?

Comment: it's an old question and I'm not using this tool anymore, what I can advice you to do is to loop the items in `sheet.Drawings` and check if it can be cast to `ExcelPicture`. I hope this helps.

Comment: okay thank you so much. I tried that,but still being cast as null.

I hope someone sees this comment and help me out

Answer (score 3):

all xlsx files are really zip files. you can copy/rename the .xlsx extension to .zip and navigate the folder hierarchy yourself. navigate to xl/media to see your images. there are certainly more efficient ways of doing this, but this is a quick and dirty solution that will get the job done.

Comment: This won't work if I have many worksheets with many pictures, picture name in the package is not the same as picture/drawing name the worksheet. I prefer direct access to image rather than extracting archive and parsing xml files to find the correct image.

Answer (score 1):

Stumbled across this when I was looking myslef to extract the image from excel sheet using EPplus. My requirement was to get the corresponding row/col as well as I wanted to associate the image to the row I have read it from.

```
var workbook = xlPackage.Workbook;
//You can resolve it by worksheet name if you using multiple sheet
ExcelWorksheet ws = workbook.Worksheets[0];
//Create a lookup of drawings per sheet
var lkDrawings = ws.Drawings.ToLookup(x => $"{ x.From.Row}_{x.From.Column}");


//now you can use this lookup while iterating your cells and save it as image. 
//You can look at example of iterating epplus cells 
//or ping me if you need more details on that.

 var lookUpKey = $"{rowCounter}_{col}";
 if(lkDrawings.Contains(lookUpKey))
 {
    ExcelPicture image = lkDrawings[lookUpKey].ToList()[0] as ExcelPicture;

    image.Image.Save($"{rowCounter}_{col}.png");
 }
```

Comment: I think in case of ExcelPosition.From and ExcelPosition.To the index works a bit differently (starts from 0) then ExcelSheet.Dimensions (starts from 1). I did it like this and above solution works for me.

`var lookUpKey = $"{rowCounter-1}_{col-1}";`