# How to convert an excel with product name and corresponding Product images in cells and store into sqlserver

Tags: c#, asp.net, webapi

I have an excel sheet that contains a list of products along with its images. I have to receive them in my web API and store them into my DB.

How can I do this? I know how to parse a single image and the data but I don't know how to parse an entire excel sheet full of them

Thank you

Comment: Where did you receive the excel file ? in which type it did you get like stream or byte array? if files comes with above data types then we can manipulate in any application.

Comment: The excel file is that of a product list from a shop. I want to be able to let the shop owner upload excel sheets,so that I can update their product list in my website

Comment: How are you reading the data from Excel? There are many different ways of reading them, each with different wrinkles as to how to get the images from them. For instance, [this question's answers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36457242/215552) detail how to read images using the EPPlus library.

Comment: var filesReadToProvider = await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync();
            var fileBytes = (byte[])null;
            var fileName = (string)null;
            foreach (var stream in filesReadToProvider.Contents)
            {
                fileBytes = await stream.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
                fileName = stream.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName;
            }

This is how I used to read an image. I wasn't sure how to read an image within an excel

Comment: Are you manipulating this through webApi or web application ?

Comment: I am manipulating thorugh a webapi

Comment: I tried using epp plus but it throws an error Could not load the file 'PresentationCore'.

when I try to run the file @HereticMonkey if the reference is not there,it works fine