# Trying To Read excel file with epp plus,but images in a cell being read as null

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, asp.net-web-api, epplus

I am trying to read a product list uploaded to a web API as excel and store it into my database.

I am parsing the excel using epp plus, it reads all the texts, but the product image in the cell is being read as null, while there are images in these cells. I am using a shaman epp plus. as epp plus throws an error while running in web APIs

Could you tell me how to read the images as well?

here is my code

```
public async Task<List<string>> UploadAsync()
{
    ExcelPackage excelPackage = new ExcelPackage();
    var context = HttpContext.Current;
    List<string> excelData = new List<string>();


    if (!Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent())
    {
        throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.UnsupportedMediaType);
    }
        var filesReadToProvider = await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync();


    foreach (HttpContent ctnt in filesReadToProvider.Contents)
    {
        //now read individual part into STREAM
        var stream = await ctnt.ReadAsStreamAsync();
        ExcelPackage excelPackage1 = new ExcelPackage(stream);

        foreach (ExcelWorksheet worksheet in excelPackage1.Workbook.Worksheets)
        {
            var temp1 = worksheet.Dimension.End.Row;
            //loop all rows
            for (int i = worksheet.Dimension.Start.Row; i <= worksheet.Dimension.End.Row; i++)
            {
                //loop all columns in a row
                for (int j = worksheet.Dimension.Start.Column; j <= worksheet.Dimension.End.Column; j++)
                {
                    //add the cell data to the List
                    if (worksheet.Cells[i, j].Value != null)
                    {
                        excelData.Add(worksheet.Cells[i, j].Value.ToString());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return excelData;


}
```

Comment: Have you looked at this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36457242/how-to-get-read-picture-from-excel-file-xlsx-using-epplus

Comment: yes I did mate

I tried using

                                var name = worksheet.Drawings[0].Name;
                                var pic = worksheet.Drawings[name] as ExcelPicture;


But its all null,the name and the pic variable @ScottHannen